# Why the newly created memory is mapped to /dev/zero (deleted) in mmap()

Tags: c, linux

I have created a block of memory of 4K using mmap.

```
kg>./a.out &
[1] 23286

 Memory Address : 0xb7f6f000

kg>pmap 23286
23286:   ./a.out
0053d000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]
08048000      4K r-x--  /home/trng3/sh/POC/a.out
08049000      4K rwx--  /home/trng3/sh/POC/a.out
46f46000    100K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.5.so
46f5f000      4K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.5.so
46f60000      4K rwx--  /lib/ld-2.5.so
46f68000   1244K r-x--  /lib/libc-2.5.so
4709f000      8K r-x--  /lib/libc-2.5.so
470a1000      4K rwx--  /lib/libc-2.5.so
470a2000     12K rwx--    [ anon ]
b7f57000      4K rw---    [ anon ]
b7f6f000      4K rw-s-  /dev/zero (deleted)
b7f70000      4K rw---    [ anon ]
bfd18000     88K rw---    [ stack ]
 total     1488K
```

When I calculated the size (btwn b7f6f000 and b7f70000) it comes as 1000 bytes instead of 4K. why is the memory not getting created as 4K? . Why the newly created memory is mapped to /dev/zero (deleted) . Is the rw-s- , s is a swap space.

source code :

```
int main(){
 /* Variables */
 create_memory();
 return SUCCESS;
}

/* Create Memory Region in User Space in RAM */
int create_memory(){

 ptr_file_sys = mmap(NULL,4096,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED,-1,0);
 if(MAP_FAILED == ptr_file_sys){
  error_print("\n Cannot allocate memory space!\n");
 }
 else{
  debug_print("\n Memory Address : 0x%x \n",ptr_file_sys);
 }

 return SUCCESS;
}

int delete_memory(){
 munmap(ptr_file_sys,4096);
}
```

Comment: That's 0x1000 -> 4096.

Comment: Thanks. I forget to convert it to decimal.

Comment: Why do you think your mapping is the one to `/dev/zero`? There are a couple of anonymous 4k blocks as well that it could be (and most probably is).

Comment: @Joachim : becoz the memory address returned by mmap is 0xb7f6f000

Comment: In your opinion, what else should it be mapped to but `/dev/zero`? A mapping not backed by a file (you did not mention a file) is guaranteed to be zero-initialized. Try to write a single byte to that range and dump the mappings again, I wouldn't be surprised if the mapping _magically_ changed to `[anon]`. It is much more efficient for the OS to simply map to `/dev/zero` as long as you never access the memory, rather than giving you a (possibly very large) section of memory which it _must_ initialize and which _must_ exist physically.

Comment: Show your source code please. And learn about `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (which is better than `open`-ing explicitly `/dev/zero`)

Comment: I have updated the question with the source code .

Comment: @Basile : I'm using an ANONYMOUS mapping only

Comment: ... which is guaranteed to be zero-initialized. Thus, `/dev/zero`, until you write to it.